# How to fix a pod install error for the DeepAR in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, pod-install, deepar

I'm using the rwa_deep_ar package for the DeepAR feature in the Flutter project. When I install the pod in MacOS, I see the following error.
[image]

I want to know how to fix this error and how to use the DeepAR for iOS in Flutter.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messaegin text form and your attempts to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your iOS folder and check if the `rwa_deep_ar.podspec` is exist in `.symlinks/plugins/rwa_deep_ar/ios`.
Afaik, this package is based on `camera_deep_ar` and the author forgot to migrate the iOS part to the new name.